# How to Normalize Counts Correctly?

Tags: inference, count-data, biostatistics

I am not sure what is this type of problem called, so a ref would do wonders.

I am calculating the heritability of diseases among a population. Here is the catch: the age distribution of diagnosis may (likely) not match the age distribution of the population.

My sample are under 40s mostly, thus they will have a limited window of time to develop many diseases, as some diseases only appear later in life. Right now I am looking to find the fraction of = (count inherited disease) / (count total). Thus if I try to estimate the heritability of a disease that appears only later, the (count total) will be overestimated due to there being so many young people who never got to develop the disease.

I am thinking of just setting a cuttoff minimal age to start counting the total people, which is the age at which 50% are diagnosed in the sample. But I feel like there should be a general way for me to adjust using the distributions themselves.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you are trying to do survival analysis.